# Add class to <select> if has been clicked or changed (js or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a select ([bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) so it behave like dropdown list), I'd like to know if select has been clicked or changed to add some class with css.

[image]

```
  <select required class="form-control selectpicker" title="shipping">
      <option>Standard</option>
      <option>Express</option>
      <option>...</option>
  <select>
```

I wanted to add my class only to this particular select element - if check change color to green, and if it was clicked but not changed add class with color red;

code also here https://jsfiddle.net/rumsugrw/

Comment: Answer is in the [Events](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events) section of the plugin docs

Comment: Don't ask questions and down vote answers if you have 49 points ;)
No one will help you if you are like that:)

Comment: @Anokrize OP didn't downvote your answer...I did. It was not valid. I already gave you a demo to show why also along with explanation that you didn't pay attention to fact OP is using a plugin

Comment: i didn't downvote any answer (although none of them works for me :/ )

Comment: and i have no idea why some people downvote my question, couse I really  have no idea how to fix it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your js, write the following code:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
   $(this).closest('.bootstrap-select').addClass("checked");
});
```

On change of your selectpicker, this will add the required class to your selectbox.
Also, change your css to this:

```
.bootstrap-select.checked > .dropdown-toggle > span {
  color: red
}
```

Updated the fiddle. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rumsugrw/35/

Answer (score 0):

Use the **event**: [changed.bs.select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events)

```
// this function is called on every changes
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {
 var value = $(this).val();
 // do some conditions here...
});
```